# Minimizing setOnSeekBarChangeListener Boilerplate

Tags: java, android, abstract, inner-classes

In an attempt to write a bit less code every time I wanted a SeekBar and a corresponding TextView showing it's numerical value, I wrote the following abstract class:

```
abstract public class SeekBarWrapper {
SeekBar bar;
TextView valueText;
int value = 0;
int minValue;
int divisor;

public SeekBarWrapper(SeekBar sb, TextView tv, int value,  int minValue,
    int divisor){
    this.bar = sb;
    this.valueText = tv;
    this.value = value;
    this.minValue = minValue;
    this.divisor = divisor;
    setListener();
}

private void setListener(){
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
            if(!fromUser) return;
            value = progress + minValue;
            valueText.setText(Integer.toString(value/divisor));
            sendValue();
        }
    });
}

abstract protected void sendValue();

public void updateValue(int newValue){
    if(newValue == value) return;
    value = newValue;
    valueText.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    bar.setProgress(value*divisor-minValue);
}

}
```

For each concrete SeekBar I'll write a nested class, for example:

```
class VolumeBarWrapper extends SeekBarWrapper{
    public VolumeBarWrapper(SeekBar s, TextView t, int v,  int min, int div){
        super(s, t, v, min, div);
    }
    public void sendValue(){
        someCallback.volume(this.value);
    }
}
```

And instantiate like so:

```
VolumeBarWrapper volume;
    // later:
    volume = new VolumeBarWrapper((SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.volume_bar),
            (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volume_value), 300, 0, 70);
```

It's functional, and seemingly an improvement.  What I would like to know:

1. Is there is some way to make this an anonymous inner class, or another method to further condense the per-instance code?
   And less pressingly:
2. Am I abusing the "wrapper" label, doesn't it have some specialized meaning in pattern-speak?
3. Is this design "bad" from an OOP perspective (I'm still trying to school myself in this regard)?

Comment: I ultimately went with a concrete version of the wrapper above with a custom listener as described below. This made using both SeekBar and VerticalSeekBar seamless, whereas with the extended SeekBar I would have had to subclass for each and change the references in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make a *better* `SeekBar` , and use it everywhere:

```
public class VersatileSeekBar extends SeekBar implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private ChangeHandler mChangeHandler;

    public void bindDisplayToChange(TextView textView,ChangeHandler handler) {
        mTextView = textView;
        mChangeHandler = handler;
    }

    public VersatileSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VersatileSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public VersatileSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }


    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        if(mChangeHandler != null && mTextView != null){
            mChangeHandler.onChange(i,mTextView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    private void init(){
        this.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    public static abstract class ChangeHandler{
        public abstract void onChange(int value,TextView textView);
    }
}
```

Code to call :

```
myVersatileSeekBar.bindDisplayToChange(myTextView, new VersatileSeekBar.ChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(int value, TextView textView) {
                textView.setText("level :" + value * 100);
            }
        });
```

Comment: The one crucial feature of my abstract class is the ability to put a call to an overrideable abstract method in the onProgressChanged method. Is there some way to manage this without extending the SimpleSeekBar for every instance? If no, this is possibly more elegant, but I might prefer to stick with an abstact class.

Comment: @anthropomo you can now supply any implementation of `ChangeHandler`to update the `TextView`, see updated answer.

Comment: I was googling "custom java listener" and skimming the GoF Observer pattern while flipping back here. This example will save me several attempts. Thank you!